# usage of have been

Tags: tense

Are the following sentences correct:

> I haven't been able to access Facebook for the last few days. I'm able to get on just fine now, though.

Note that I am able to access Facebook now.

I’m most concerned about if I am using “have been” correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is exactly how you use the present perfect, to describe some event or action that has continued up to (around) the present moment:

> He **has practiced** the piano every day of his adult life.
>
> He **has read** the newspaper every morning this week, to try and catch up on current events.
>
> She **hasn't been** home at all for the past few days.  I wonder if she's on vacation?

Some recommend that since you are able to go on Facebook *now* you should use the simple past:

> I **wasn't** able to get onto Facebook for the last few days, but now ...

But native English speakers are just as likely to use the present perfect, so I think it's fine either way.